# WebDAV and Windows 7, no write access

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, windows-7, apache-2.4, webdav

I have configured my Apache 2.4.10 with WebDAV:

```
DavLockDB "/etc/httpd/var/DavLock"

Alias /public "/srv/webdav/public"

<Directory "/srv/webdav/public">
Dav On

AllowOverride None
Options Indexes

AuthType Digest
AuthName 7ooo
AuthUserFile "/etc/httpd/user.passwd"
AuthDigestProvider file

<Limit GET HEAD OPTIONS PROPFIND>
    Require all granted
</Limit>

<LimitExcept GET HEAD OPTIONS PROPFIND>
    Require user webdav
</LimitExcept>
</Directory>
```

All necessary files and folders exist and have appropriate permissions.

If I connect to the WebDAV using Windows Explorer under Windows 7 64bit, I can read files and change to subdirectories. However, I can't write any new or existing files. Windows Explorer just hangs indefinitely. Same with notepad.

What's wrong with my config?

Strangely, other WebDAV clients such as cadaver or even an iPhone app are working perfectly.

Also, if I just put "Require all granted" (without Limit) in front of the LimitExcept clause, write access works fine (for all users, not just the user "webdav").

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your apache logs show you are properly authenticated as the webdav user? Sounds like digest authentication may not be working properly.

Take a look at this blog post: http://dark9t.github.io/blog/2014/06/02/why-digest-authentication-fails-in-windows-7-mini-redirector/

You may want to play with keepalive parameters (even more if you have proxies), but switching to HTTP Basic authentication / SSL would be simpler and not less secure.

Comment: Btw, you van temporarily switch to basic auth by changing the apache directives: AuthType Basic, and remove AuthDigestProvider. If write works just move to https (which preferred anyway by nowadays clients.